# Network centric application

Tags: javascript

Javascript is said to be designed for creating network-centric applications.

from my readings, network-centric applications are applications that send data to the server and are interconnected by a communications network.

Can you explain what the term network-centric application mean?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is requesting a definition for a term that is ill-defined in the first place. Maybe it would be easier to help if you could provide a citation for your claim in the first sentence.

Answer (score -1):

Facebook would be a perfect example. Sure it falls under the category of social network as well, but from a tech standpoint it's a very large network-centric application.

It not only connects people with each other but through things like push notifications, synchronization, being able to use multiple devices, etc., it is a comprehensive network-centric app.